# how to format array param in pgsql?

Tags: c++, arrays, postgresql

I pass a string from c as"{1,2,3,4,5}",and try use it to update  array int[] record in a table as `format("UPDATE table SET array = %s WHERE *** ",string)`

but get the error

```
"lastError = 0x009f0bda "ERROR:  column "houses_list" is of type integer[] but expression is of type text"
```

please give a correct format of update array use string in pgsql,tks

Answer (score 2):

You can try `'{1,2,3,4,5}'::int[]` or `ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]`.